# ListView in Fragment vs ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I am trying to use ViewPager to implement a sliding system between a couple fragments I have. I have 2 fragments and 1 listfragment. How would I go about populating the viewpager with both of these types of fragments? Or would it be easier to implement a ListView in the fragment so I have 3 fragments?

I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. I have 3 Fragments: 2 classes extend 'Fragment' while the third extends 'ListFragment'. In my ViewPagerActivity, when I am adding my fragments to a list:

```
public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();

    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    fList.add(MainActivity.newInstance());
    //fList.add(MainActivity.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
    //fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 2"));
    //fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 3"));

    return fList;
}
```

}

I am getting an error at the line:

```
fList.add(MainActivity.newInstance());
```

Which is my ListFragment class (I know MainActivity throws it off but it is my ListFragment class). My listfragment class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListFragment {

private List<ListViewItem> mItems;

public static MainActivity newInstance()
{
    MainActivity f = new MainActivity();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    Resources resources = getResources();
    setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
    getListView().setDivider(null);
}
```

}

Basically, it is giving me an error because I am passing in newInstance of ListFragment but the List type is Fragments. I didn't think there should be a problem because ListFragment is a subclass of Fragment.

Error: add(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in list cannot be applied to /MainActivity

This is why I am not sure if I should use a fragment+listview to overcome this error.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. A `ListFragment` is just a `Fragment` with some convenience methods to handle a `ListView`. If you decide to use a `Fragment` which has a `ListView` and do everything yourself, you're simply creating your own version of a `ListFragment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your Fragment is from support library but the ViewPager is expecting the standard Fragment

Comment: That fixed it. In my ListFragment I was importing android.app.ListFragment, but in my ViewPagerActivity I was importing android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Just curious, why are there two sets of libraries? Does it matter which you use? This has always confused me.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager actually doesn't care about types of fragments, even pager adapter doesn't as long as fragments extend `Fragment`, which `ListFragment` of course does.

Comment: @anvesh95 in this case answer from Sugesh seems a good suggestion, check fully qualified names of your fragment classes, some may come from the support library and some do not.

Comment: That fixed it, but I am not sure what is the difference between support library and standard library.

Comment: @anvesh95 `Fragment` as a component was added in API 11, if you want to make your app compatible with previous android versions, you may want to use support libraries. It's not only about fragments, they backport many features that were added in following android versions.